# How to override EditPopup method on my own payment plugin NopCommerce?

Tags: nopcommerce-4.0

I'm developing my own payment plugin on NopCommerce, my payment plugin requires additional info from the shop owner which I implemented on the config page, I want to prevent the owner to enable the plugin until he enters the required info correctly.

the button "is enabled" on the edit pop up can be changed unconditionally, is there a way to override the method "EditPopup" on the "PluginController" ? so I can make sure the plugin is not enabled until the config info is entered correctly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FenB4.jpg)